# How can you use .NET Core to support Safe Curves in ECC (eg. Curve25519)

Tags: .net, cryptography, .net-core, elliptic-curve

It appears that .NET Core supports creation of custom curves in ECC.

I've tried to define the Curve25519, as shown below:

```
public class Curves
{
    // TODO: check the key gen rand.
    public static ECCurve Curve25519
    {
        get
        {
            return new ECCurve()
            {
                CurveType = ECCurve.ECCurveType.PrimeMontgomery,
                B = new byte[] { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
                A = new byte[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,109,6},
                G = new ECPoint()
                {
                    X = new byte[] { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9},
                    Y = new byte[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 }},
                Prime = new byte[] { 127, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 237 },
                Order = new byte[] {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8},
                Cofactor = new byte[] { 1 } // fix later
            };
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to define it

```
var ecc2 = ECDsa.Create(Curves.Curve25519);
```

I get a null pointer exception.

Does anyone see any obvious error, or is there still not much support for explicit curves in .NET Core?

Comment: Any chance to see whole stacktrace from error?

Comment: very itnerested in this too

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Comment: I get a different exception. Very interested in this problem.
Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: The requested operation is not supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Errors are being raised because Curve25519 is designed for ECDH key exchange calculations, specifically X25519. Details of this usage is at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039528/why-does-curve25519-calculate-key-pair-correctly-even-though-its-parameters-are).

ECDSA should be used over twisted Edwards version of Curve25519, namely Ed25519. This curve can be defined and used in .Net Core as below.

```
ECCurve ecCurve = new ECCurve() // Ed25519, 32 bytes, 256 bit
{
    CurveType = ECCurve.ECCurveType.PrimeTwistedEdwards,
    A = new byte[] { 0x7f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
      0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xec }, // GF(-1)
    B = new byte[] { 0x52, 0x03, 0x6C, 0xEE, 0x2B, 0x6F, 0xFE, 0x73, 0x8C, 0xC7, 0x40, 0x79, 0x77, 0x79, 0xE8, 0x98,
      0x00, 0x70, 0x0A, 0x4D, 0x41, 0x41, 0xD8, 0xAB, 0x75, 0xEB, 0x4D, 0xCA, 0x13, 0x59, 0x78, 0xA3 },
    G = new ECPoint()
    {
      X = new byte[] { 0x21, 0x69, 0x36, 0xD3, 0xCD, 0x6E, 0x53, 0xFE, 0xC0, 0xA4, 0xE2, 0x31, 0xFD, 0xD6, 0xDC, 0x5C,
        0x69, 0x2C, 0xC7, 0x60, 0x95, 0x25, 0xA7, 0xB2, 0xC9, 0x56, 0x2D, 0x60, 0x8F, 0x25, 0xD5, 0x1A },
      Y = new byte[] { 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66,
        0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x58 }
    },
    Prime = new byte[] { 0x7f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff,
      0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xed },
    Order = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
      0x14, 0xde, 0xf9, 0xde, 0xa2, 0xf7, 0x9c, 0xd6, 0x58, 0x12, 0x63, 0x1a, 0x5c, 0xf5, 0xd3, 0xed },
    Cofactor = new byte[] { 8 }
};
```

Parameter A is -1, above representation is -1 in Galois Field of 2^255-19. This can be calculated by evaluating below code at [SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/).

```
gf=GF(2^255-19)
print (hex(gf(-1)))
```

But, [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography#ecdsa) says explicit curves are not supported on below Windows 10 and macOS, and my tries show they throw exceptions on Linux. So, if platforms other than Windows 10 or inter-platform operability is needed, libraries like [NSec](https://nsec.rocks/) or [libsodium-core](https://github.com/tabrath/libsodium-core) should be used.