# Curve25519 exchange between BouncyCastle and .NET

Tags: .net, cryptography, ecdh, curve-25519, x25519

I wrote X25519 curve parameters in .NET and thought to cross-check it between this piece and BouncyCastle. The following is the code. But it fails to export the BouncyCastle key.

There will be an exception

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Key is not a valid public or private key.

when I try to import the key between steps 3 and 4 (see code).

I'm a bit at loss what could be the reason for that.

Hints, tips or anything to push towards making this work would be much appreciated. How to make this cross-check work? What do I miss? Is there something with the curve?

```cs
public static ECCurve Curve25519 => new()
{
    CurveType = ECCurve.ECCurveType.PrimeMontgomery,

    //In NIST.SP.800-186-draft.pdf: 'A'.
    A = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x07, 0x6d, 0x06 }, // 486662

    //In NIST.SP.800-186-draft.pdf: 'B'.
    B = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },

    G = new ECPoint()
    {
        //In NIST.SP.800-186-draft.pdf: 'Gu'.
        X = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9 },

        //Y = Gy2.ToByteArray(true, true),
        //In NIST.SP.800-186-draft.pdf: 'Gu'.
        Y = new byte[] { 0x2f, 0xaf, 0x1f, 0xaf, 0xbf, 0xa0, 0x86, 0xb4, 0xe0, 0x1e, 0xdd, 0x2c, 0x77, 0x48, 0xd1, 0x4c, 0x92, 0x3d, 0x4d, 0x7e, 0x6d, 0x7c, 0x61, 0xb2, 0x29, 0xe9, 0xc5, 0xa2, 0x7e, 0xce, 0xd3, 0xd9 }
    },

    //Prime = p = 2^255 - 19.
    Prime = new byte[] { 0x7f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xed },

    //Prime = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },

    //In NIST.SP.800-186-draft.pdf: 'n'.
    Order = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x14, 0xde, 0xf9, 0xde, 0xa2, 0xf7, 0x9c, 0xd6, 0x58, 0x12, 0x63, 0x1a, 0x5c, 0xf5, 0xd3, 0xed },

    //In NIST.SP.800-186-draft.pdf: 'h'.
    Cofactor = new byte[] { 8 }
};


public void CrossCheck25519UsingBouncyCastleAndDotNet()
{
    // Step 1: Bob generates keys using BouncyCastle
    var randomGenerator = new SecureRandom();
    var bobPrivateKeyBouncy = new X25519PrivateKeyParameters(randomGenerator);
    X25519PublicKeyParameters bobPublicKeyBouncy = bobPrivateKeyBouncy.GeneratePublicKey();

    // Alternatively...
    // var keys = keyGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();
    // var bobPublicKeyBouncy = (X25519PublicKeyParameters)keys.Public;
    // var bobPrivateKeyBouncy = (X25519PrivateKeyParameters)keys.Private;

    // Step 2: Bob sends his public key to Alice            
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(bobPublicKeyBouncy);
    byte[] bobPublicKeyBytes = publicKeyInfo.GetDerEncoded();

    // Step 3: Alice receives Bob's public key and generates her own keys using .NET
    using(var alice = ECDiffieHellman.Create(Curve25519))
    {
        // This fails. Is the reason Curve25519 parameters or that BouncyCastle exported keys are in wrong format?
        alice.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(bobPublicKeyBytes, out _);

        // Alice calculates the shared secret
        byte[] aliceSharedSecret = alice.DeriveKeyFromHash(alice.PublicKey, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

        // Step 4: Alice sends her public key to Bob
        byte[] alicePublicKeyBytes = alice.PublicKey.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();

        // Step 5: Bob imports Alice's public key using BouncyCastle
        var alicePublicKeyBouncy = new X25519PublicKeyParameters(alicePublicKeyBytes, 0);

        // Step 6: Bob calculates the shared secret using BouncyCastle
        var bobAgreement = new X25519Agreement();
        bobAgreement.Init(bobPrivateKeyBouncy);
        byte[] bobSharedSecret = new byte[bobAgreement.AgreementSize];
        bobAgreement.CalculateAgreement(alicePublicKeyBouncy, bobSharedSecret, 0);

        // Step 7: Compare the shared secrets
        Assert.Equal(bobSharedSecret, aliceSharedSecret);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check `Gv` (what you call `G.Y`) in your parameters (s. [RFC 7748](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7748#section-4.1)) The algorithms behind ECDH and X25519 are different (curve form and other details), so even if no exception is thrown, it wouldn't surprise me if the shared secrets don't match.

Comment: A good point. So, if I do `Y = BigInteger.Parse("14781619447589544791020593568409986887264606134616475288964881837755586237401").ToByteArray(isUnsigned: true, isBigEndian: true)` (if I got that correctly), the exception at `alice.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(bobPublicKeyBytes, out _);` still persists. Here I were, simply trying to take two libraries and get them to agree. Seems to get complicated!

Comment: As said, ECDH and X25519 require curves of different forms (ECDH: short Weierstrass form, X25519: curve25519, a Montgomery curve). Besides the curve forms, there are further differences in the algorithms. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65039528/9014097) addresses those differences as well.

Comment: I try to use Curve25519 in X25519 ECDH using these two "counterpart libraries". Should it not work? Hmm, I feel I miss something now, a mental block or something.